# При вызове команды в Гит Баше происходит ошибка

Tags: git, github, git-commit

```
User@DESKTOP-ITUEQG4 MINGW64 /d/Программирование/downloads/Git/forGit/hexlet-git1 (main)
$ git commit --amend
hint: Waiting for your editor to close the file...
"D:\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" -w: D:\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe: No such file or directory
error: There was a problem with the editor '"D:\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" -w'.
Please supply the message using either -m or -F option.
```

Comment: Извините а как перенастроить путь для редактора?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас настроен Sublime Text как редактор сообщений для git, но git его не нашел по указанному пути (`D:\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe: No such file or directory` - нет такого файла или директории). Нужно перенастроить правильный путь для редактора, или передавать путь с помощью опции -m команды `git commit`, т.е. в вашем случае:

```
git commit --amend -m "Сообщение коммита"
```

Пример команды для изменения редактора для git:

```
git config --global core.editor "C:/Program Files/папка редактора/редактор.exe"
```

Также советую почитать: [1.6 Введение - Первоначальная настройка Git](https://git-scm.com/book/ru/v2/%D0%92%D0%B2%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%9F%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B9%D0%BA%D0%B0-G)